# Anyone know where i can find a glsl implementation of a bilateral filter (blur)?

Tags: graphics, opengl-es

I'm looking to do a "selective blur" or "surface blur" on the GPU. I've read some research papers on the subject, and seen a good deal of C code, but ideally I'd like something in GLSL, HSL, or CG.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Actually, a bilateral blur is not very different from a gaussian blur, you just have to multiply the value of the sample by the gaussian factor multiplied by the result of a "closeness' function between the actual values of the centre pixel and the sampled pixel.

So, in pseude GLSL

```
vec3 centreColour = texture2D(image,texCoord);
vec3 result = centreColour;
float normalization = 1;
for (int i = 0; i < NUM_SAMPLES; ++1)
{
   vec3 sample = texture2D(image, texCoord + offsets[i]);
   float gaussianCoeff = computeGaussianCoeff(offsets[i]);

   //depends on your implementation, this is quick
   float closeness = 1.0f - distance(sample,centreColour) / length(vec3(1,1,1));

   float sampleWeight = closeness * gaussian;

   result += sample * sampleWeight;
   noralization += sampleWeight;
}
vec3 bilateral = result / normalization;
```

You should probably have a better way to determine the closeness value, eg do it in a perceptively uniform space such as LUV.

For optimization, you can apply all techniques that work for gaussian blur, apart from the ones that ignore the fact you have to know the pixel's value. For example, with a pure gaussian you can choose your texcoords wisely and integrate 4 pixels in one fetch. That won't work.

The big things that do work:

*Separate your filter. Instead of 5x5 samples (25), do 5 horizontally, save to an intermediate buffer, and do 5 vertically. It won't look exactly the same, but it will still remove noise.

*Perform your filter on a lower resolution, and composit it with the orignal to get some detail back.

Comment: Thanks, that's more digestible than most of what I've read, and thanks for the tips on what I can and cannot do in terms of optimization. I'll see if I can translate this into a Quartz Composer example. For clarification, my goal with this is to smooth an image while maintaining detail in edges.

Comment: This is exactly what a bilateral doise, it removes noise while maintaining detail. It's also a favorite of mine when photoshopping :)

Comment: Just stumbled upon this post and I thought I'd link to a couple of simple QC experiments that does bilateral filtering: https://github.com/lbergnehr/quartz-compositions

Comment: One of the most common ways of optimizing 2D gaussian blurs is to take advantage of the kernel separability. Note that this doesn't apply trivially to bilateral blurs.

Comment: Should the line for closeness be "float closeness = 1.0 - distance(sample,centreColour) / length(vec3(1,1,1));" instead, or am I missing something? The weight should get smaller as the colors become more different, right?

Answer (score 1):

For anyone who get here, if you don't re-implement by your own, there is a fully implementation in [GPUImageView for Android](https://github.com/cats-oss/android-gpuimage/blob/master/library/src/main/java/jp/co/cyberagent/android/gpuimage/filter/GPUImageBilateralBlurFilter.java).

The implementation include vertex shader and fragment shader.